# Using Analysis Tools on SonarQube not containing in the Java Ecosystem Plugin

Tags: sonarqube, pmd

I'm setting up a project environment for a bigger Java project and plan to use SonarQube with PMD, Findbugs and JaCoco. Theses tools are already included in SonarQube with the Java Ecosystem Plugins, but not all the new versions are supported.

In specific, PMD has only support for version 4.3 (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PMD+Plugin), which is 2 years old now. Is there any possibility to install/use the newest version of PMD with SonarQube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

For your information, you shouldn't need to use PMD anymore. See http://www.sonarqube.org/already-158-checkstyle-and-pmd-rules-deprecated-by-sonarqube-java-rules/.

You can also follow and vote for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-26